# angular 2 CLI live reload is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am creating angular 2 application through "angular-cli" version "1.0.0-beta.28.3".

When I am using commands "npm start" or "ng serve", the app is working at 
http://localhost:4200

But, when changing some code for type Script file or CSS, the live refresh for  browser is not happening. What's wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: What is your console log after starting application? Everething OK?

Comment: Yes, everything is OK...Thankks

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42006139/not-able-to-change-anything-in-angular2-application-when-i-create-it-using-angul?noredirect=1#comment71188422_42006139

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try deleting your `node_modules` folder and running `npm install` again. This should upgrade a bad npm dependency.

By the way, you might also want to upgrade to Angular CLI beta 29 as beta 28.3 has a few issues in general. If you do so, note that the package name has changed in beta.29 from `angular-cli` to `@angular/cli`.