# Not able to change anything in Angular2 application when i create it using Angular CLI

Tags: angular, typescript

Using `ng serve` the project runs in localhost but after changing the code it does not refresh.

Lets say we have the general "App Works!!" in the initial project. However, it doesn't change if I edit inside the `application.component.ts` the "App works" to "Hello". It still shows App Works!!

what's the problem. Help me out.

Comment: are you saving your changes while angular cli is running in cmd window?

Comment: Yes i'm saving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug within the latest `@ngtools/webpack` package that the angular-cli uses. To fix this you need to manually downgrade the package:

```
npm uninstall @ngtools/webpack
npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4
```

After a new cli version, you should remove this from your `package.json` again

For more information check [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4338) bug report

Comment: @sushilsuthar yes, I wasted 3 hours of my morning today on this issue :)

Comment: yes me too wasted almost 2 hours. thanks to you to save my 1 hour.

Comment: if you use docker you should read this: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/webpack-watch-in-vagrant-docker/

Answer (score 1):

The solution for Ubuntu webpack rebuild issue.

The problem seems to be the inotify max_user_watches :

```
sudo echo "fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288" >> /etc/sysctl.conf

sudo sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

Comment: Using >> in the command even after adding sudo might result in 'permission denied', to resolve this issue, follow this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84882/sudo-echo-something-etc-privilegedfile-doesnt-work-is-there-an-alterna

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with Ubuntu 16.04. Quick fix:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Hope this helps someone!