# What's going on with my new install of @angular/cli? (webpack compile fails silently)

Tags: angular, webpack, angular-cli

I updated my cli to `1.0.0-beta.30` this morning. I was getting this message on `1.0.0-beta.24`, but my app would still build and function as normal, so I just ignored it. Now I get the html shell served, but my application won't start and there is no console output at all. What's happening here?

(I'm on Windows 10)
[image: CLI output]

My `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "search-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

my `angular-cli.json`:

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.30",
    "name": "search-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "files": "src/**/*.ts",
      "project": "src/tsconfig.json"
    },
    {
      "files": "e2e/**/*.ts",
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false,
    "inline": {
      "style": false,
      "template": false
    },
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": false,
      "directive": false,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": false,
      "service": false
    }
  }
}
```

My `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "",
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your tsconfig? It looks like some libraries aren't there at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

try this solution:

> This is a bug within the latest `@ngtools/webpack` package that the
>   angular-cli uses. To fix this you need to manually downgrade the
>   package:
>
> ```
> npm uninstall @ngtools/webpack
> npm install --save-dev @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4
> ```
>
> After a new cli version, you should remove this from your
>   `package.json` again
>
> For more information check
>   [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4338) bug report

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42006228/3676586

Comment: Done, but same result. `rm -rf`'d my node modules, too. `ng serve` is working on the starter application, but that seems to be the case for everyone.

Comment: someone said `It need to be "@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.4" at package.json and NOT "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.2.4"`, but someone revert to version beta-28.3, for me, i'm still using version beta-26

Comment: I'm thinking I'll revert to 26 (again) here in a bit if I can't get this figured out.

Comment: yep, maybe we'll waiting for next release