# Angular4 is not refreshing the page after code change

Tags: angular

When i changed the code in Angular4 then page is not refreshing. i have to again start the server using

```
ng serve --open
```

Every time i change I have to restart the server.

Please guide me!

Is there any other option to avoid this?

Comment: use `watch` flag too `ng serve --open --watch`

Comment: Its not working

Comment: hot/live reload is by default with angular cli, specifying watch flag explicitly is a bit weird!

Comment: which version of cli are you using?

Comment: use nodemon that will help you

Comment: i am using version 1.2.3

Comment: I would recommend updating the cli, we got lots of updates post the version you are using!

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011460/5346095

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below command in your angular root folder

```
ng server --watch
```

Answer (score 3):

try

> ng serve --open --watch

if this does not work try `cache clean` and `npm install`

If you are using Ubuntu Try reseting the number of watches this might solve the problem

`echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`

Comment: Are you running it in ubuntu or windows

Comment: Use cli version @ 1.2.4

Comment: If ubuntu Try increasing watches  `sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288
sudo sysctl -p --system`

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to check that you are running the command on the right directory. Even if you are running `ng serve` on an in-project IDE Command line, it could've changed and you might not have realized it.

`directory\your-project-folder> ng serve`

and not

`directory\other-folder-project> ng serve`

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011460/5346095), try deleting your node_modules folder and running npm install again. This should upgrade a bad npm dependency.

I would recommend deleting cache as well, follow below steps:

1. Delete node_modules folder.
2. `npm cache clean`.
3. `npm install`.

Since you are using a relatively older version of CLI, it would be better to update that as well!

Answer (score -1):

In Ubuntu run this command when your Angular page does not detect changes.

```
 echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
```

Comment: This is no different than what is suggested in the 2nd part of Vignesh's existing answer...