# How can I get angular to update after code change?

Tags: angular

UPDATED -- SOLVED

I am relatively new to programming and very new to Angular. I'm trying to follow along in a course to learn--I'm using codewithmosh, if anyone is familiar with that.

When updating my html, the browser is not refreshing and I have to manually re-serve in order to see any changes. I've already referenced

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42004888/angular-2-cli-live-reload-is-not-working/42011460#42011460) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/4329) article, but the first did not help.  Much as I'm embarrassed to say it, I'm not familiar enough with the 'dist' directory to have applied that. Could someone help me, or is there a different solution?

Best as I can tell, when the code is changed the serve piece starts looking at old stuff...so when the html is changed, I get an error like "error NG8001: 'authors' is not a known element:
1. If 'authors' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module."  But it's bogus because it works just fine after I re-serve.

I just don't know how to get it to look at the refreshing stuff correctly. I uninstalled and re-installed both webpack and node_module, neither worked.

Update: I left this out, I'm using VS Code.  And I've decided to continue on with the course pending resolution here, since it's inconvenient but not fatal.  It appears that editing templates in the component.ts files updates live just fine, but modifying the .html files is what makes it stop working correctly.

Below is what happens in the standalone command prompt when I ng serve. Not sure how to format properly, apologies!

```
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 23.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 141 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.15 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 686 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.62 MB [initial] [rendered]
Date: 2020-10-05T22:56:11.557Z - Hash: e4c32bae1bac1338266f - Time: 9337ms
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
: Compiled successfully.
```

And this is what happens after I modify the app.component.html file by deleting the  tag I'd added, and then re-adding it.

```
Date: 2020-10-05T23:00:22.833Z - Hash: 274020775ace6f38e9de
3 unchanged chunks
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 22.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 2.62 MB [initial] [rendered]
Time: 735ms
: Compiled successfully.

    ERROR in src/app/app.module.ts:14:5 - error NG6001: The class 'AppComponent' is listed in the declarations of the NgModule 'AppModule', but is not a directive, a component, or a pipe. Either remove it from the NgModule's declarations, or add an appropriate Angular decorator.

    14     AppComponent,
           ~~~~~~~~~~~~

      src/app/app.component.ts:8:14
        8 export class AppComponent {
                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~
        'AppComponent' is declared here.
    src/app/app.component.html:2:1 - error NG8001: 'authors' is not a known element:
    1. If 'authors' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

    2 <authors></authors>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
    src/app/app.component.html:3:1 - error NG8001: 'courses' is not a known element:
    1. If 'courses' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.

    3 <courses></courses>
      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

      src/app/app.component.ts:5:16
        5   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.
```

Now, this looks a lot to my (untrained) eyes like "authors" and "courses" are components that aren't plugged in right.  But if I CTRL+C and stop the serve, and then type ng serve again, it serves up just fine.

Below is the code from my courses.component.ts.  I can add the author component if you'd like but it seems redundant.

```
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import { NumberFormatStyle } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'courses',
    template: `
    <h2>{{ title }}</h2>
    <button>{{button title }} </button>
    <img src="{{ imageUrl }}"/>
    <img [src]="title" />
    `
})
export class CoursesComponent {
    title = "List of courses";
    imageUrl = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200";
    buttonTitle = "save this";
    isActive = true;
   
    
}
```

And below is my app.module.ts.

```
import { CoursesService } from './courses.service';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { CoursesComponent } from './courses.component';
import { CourseComponent } from './course/course.component';
import { AuthorsComponent } from './authors/authors.component';
import { AuthorsService } from './authors.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    CoursesComponent,
    CourseComponent,
    AuthorsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
    CoursesService,
    AuthorsService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And finally, below is my app.component.html. Editing the template or details in the courses.component.ts live-update just fine, but editing this HTML causes the browser to remove anything from the custom tags and the terminal starts throwing those errors. Native HTML updates just fine even after the issues start.

```
<h1>Angular</h1>
<authors></authors>
<courses></courses>

<h1>yo</h1>
```

Comment: Need a lot more info. How are you running the app? The IDE doesn't matter unless you explicitly set it up to run with a debugger. If you run ng serve (assuming you're using the CLI) any changes will be updated. By mentioning the dist directory it sounds like you're doing a full build each time which isn't necessary. Also, what version etc.

Comment: I'm building it in VS Code and running it from the powershell terminal there.  ng serve DOES update all the relevant changes, but making changes in the html files causes it to suddenly forget some of my stuff belongs there.  The dist directory is just something I found in the previous threads I found on it, and I don't know enough about that to apply their feedback.

Comment: Disregard VSCode for now, that doesn't matter. Are you running `ng serve`? What happens in the terminal when you save it? What version of the Angular CLI are you using? What do you mean by "is what makes it stop working correctly."?

Comment: Angular CLI: 10.1.4
Node: 12.18.3
OS: win32 x64

I updated the original post with more details for ng serve, and then what the terminal does after the component.html file has been edited.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for updating. Based on the errors you're trying to use custom elements called `authors` and `courses`. Since these are custom components you'll need to create and register them in the app module before Angular knows what to do with them. Please update your question with the component declarations and your app.module. Since Angular doesn't know about these, it effectively shorts and that's why you don't see updates in the HTML

Comment: Yep!  Challenge is, far as I can tell they DO appear to be labeled correctly. My concern is if they weren't labeled correctly, why would ng serve work before any changes? Remember, it works just fine on initial load.  It's just the changes that stop updating.

Comment: Can you create a reproduction in stackblitz? I don't see anything amiss... I'm assuming the `CoursesComponent` and `CourseComponent` (plural vs singular) are both declared separately with the correct selector etc. I don't think it'd be an issue but any other modules, nesting etc? Reproducing would help a bunch.

Comment: Um....I don't know how to do that? I can look it up and get it up tomorrow.  Based on the links I posted and related stuff, I think my code is just fine and there's something wrong with one of the dependencies/softwares/versions/etc on my system that I just can't a) find or b) fix.

Comment: Stackblitz.com is basically vscode in the browser.

Comment: ok, trying to figure out how to upload my folder instead of copy/pasting every file.  However, the links I provided from previous searches indicated that others have had this issue as well and it does not appear to live in the code, but in something on my machine that I cannot find.  What could that be?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which IDE you are using but you can use Visual Studio Code which can compile your angular application as soon as it detects any code changes. If you launch the application in browser windows then your application will get updated too.

Comment: oh man, I'm dumb, I forgot to mention that part. I AM using VSCode

Comment: The IDE of choice doesn't matter in this case based on the updates.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

I made a brand new project with test components, and they demonstrated the same issues. At some point I realized the compile happened correctly when I edited a .ts file, but broke when I edited a .html file.

Looked into my settings, and I had enabled save on change. Basically I *think* it was trying to compile mid-typing, which generated errors and caused things to get hungup. I disabled save-on-change and changed the ctrl+s hotkey to save-all.

It's worked just fine since then. Make changes, save, everything updates plenty fine.